# Site on remote server: "No input file specified."

Tags: php, flash, .htaccess, kohana

My site using frontend Flash and backend Kohana. And my backend panel worked on local. But when open admin panel on remote server, have this problem:

"No input file specified."

How can i solve this problem?

Edited:

Thats my .htaccess file:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On
# Put your installation directory here: If your URL is www.example.com/, 
# use / If your URL is www.example.com/kohana/, use /kohana/
RewriteBase /
# Do not enable rewriting for files or directories that exist

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# For reuests that are not actual files or directories, Rewrite to 
# index.php/URL

#RewriteRule ^/$ /index.php?langKey=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

When i write mysite.com/index.php/admin backend worked. But i want mysite.com/admin

Comment: I bet you were using Godaddy's hosting :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to change the last line to

```
RewriteRule .* /index.php?kohana_uri=$0 [QSA]
```

It worked for me on an apache php-fcgi configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This message means you can't see site directory. Sure that index.php exists and it is readable.
Also in some nginx configurations .htaccess isn't used